# Is my prison secure?

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, decision-problem, grid, path-finding

Your challenge is given an input of a prison layout to work out whether any of the prisoners can escape.

**Input**

Input may be in any reasonable format such as a string, array, array of arrays etc. The input will consist of three characters, in this case `#`, `P` and space. The input will not necessarily contain all three characters.

- `#`: A wall
- `P`: A prisoner
- space: An empty space

An example input will look like:

```
#####
#   #
# P #
#   #
#####
```

**Output**

A truthy/falsey value of whether or not the prison is secure. The prison is only secure if it can hold **all** of the prisoners. If **any** prisoner can escape it is not secure.

A prisoner can escape if they are not fully enclosed by a wall. A diagonal joining is fully enclosed.

**Test cases**

```
############# Truthy
# P #  P#   #
#   #   # P #
#############

############# Truthy
# P    P    #
#   #   # P #
#############

############# Falsey
# P #  P#   #
#   #   # P #
########## ##

####          Truthy
#   #
 #   #
  # P ####
  ####

P             Falsey

###           Falsey
# #
# #
### P
```

Comment: I have a feeling this is a duplicate or at least a similar challenge. Good challenge anyways.

Comment: May we require that the input be padded to a rectangle?

Comment: @JanDvorak You can have leading and trailing whitespace yes.

Comment: @JanDvorak It might be but with my limited Google Fu I could not find a duplicate.

Comment: @JanDvorak It also looks very familiar to me. I think I've seen a similar challenge in the Sandbox before, iirc.

Comment: Could you add a test case where we have a closed box, but with a prisoner outside it? I.e. `####\n#  #\n#  #\n####  P`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Added

Comment: @JanDvorak Aren't you thinking about the challenge where you had to plan the layout of the prison? Can't find it anymore but I remember it well.

Comment: I would personally move the prisoner in the third test case one place to their right so that they no longer have a direct vertical path to freedom.

Comment: Somehow  [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102133/thinking-outside-the-box-am-i-doing-it-right)

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/83808/61384) (Flood-fill a 2D grid)

Comment: It would be good to have Falsey examples where both horizontal and vertical movement are required to escape.

Comment: I wonder if there's any convenient way to interpret this input as a bitmap and use an image editor's flood fill tool on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thinking outside the box - Am I doing it right?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102133/thinking-outside-the-box-am-i-doing-it-right)

Comment: @tfbninja Not really a duplicate. That one asks to try to have the program extrapolate from given data to determine if the word is in the box. This one is BFS floodfill to see if there are unenclosed spaces holding marked values.

Comment: @tfbninja Certainly not a duplicate. The other question also restrict the wrapper to be in the shape of a box, and only give partial information. Still, useful as [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102133/thinking-outside-the-box-am-i-doing-it-right).

Comment: @HyperNeutrino and user202729 I see your point, I will remove my close vote

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### [Snails](https://github.com/feresum/PMA), 13 bytes

```
!(t\P(o\ ),o~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85LzMwp/v9fUaMkJkAjP0ZBUye/7v9/ZWTApawQoKCsoBAAxAognoICBAeAeDCgoKwMAA)

Prints `0` for insecure prisons and the size of the input's bounding box for secure prisons.

The idea is to ensure that we can't find a path from a `P` to an out of bounds cell (`~`) moving only orthogonally (`o`) through spaces. The `t` is a teleport so that regardless where we attempt the match it tries all possible starting positions to find a `P`.

Comment: The right tool.

Answer (score 16):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>485 480 474 470 421</strike> 408 bytes

The absolutely wrong tool and approach, but nonetheless...

- 7 bytes (and more) saved with the useful tips from TheLethalCoder.
- 4 bytes saved by returning an integer.
- 4 more bytes saved thanks (once again) to TheLethalCoder by replacing `' '` with `32` in the comparisons.
- LOTS of bytes saved by refactoring the code.
- 13 more bytes thanks to (guess who?) TheLethalCoder. :) I keep forgetting his tips and he keeps reminding me them.

```cs
m=>{var p='P';int a=m.Length,b=m[0].Length,i=0,j,x,y;var c=new System.Collections.Stack();for(;i<a;i++)for(j=0;j<b;j++)if(m[i][j]==p)c.Push(new[]{i,j});while(c.Count>0){var t=(int[])c.Pop();x=t[0];y=t[1];if(x<1|x>a-2|y<1|y>b-2)return 0;foreach(var v in new[]{-1,1}){var z=x>0&x<a-1&y>0&y<b-1;if(z&m[x+v][y]==32){m[x][y]=p;c.Push(new[]{x+v,y});}if(z&m[x][y+v]==32){m[x][y]=p;c.Push(new[]{x,y+v});}}}return 1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5VJRa9swEH7vrzgaSC1iGzt7lBUYgT11YMhgD8YPiqok8mI5yEpqN/Vvz07JvC5QiunLVnYg605836fPpxN1ICojT4AhtryuITWqrvRCir2RN@74eP66qC23SsChUg/wlSvt1dYovc5y4GZdk9@4F4aLRVtbWYZf9lokYsNNlme5r7SdwQoYnEo2Ox64gR27S@8ongNnZXgv9dpu/CUrsyjvK8Uiv/Abv6WOIJiWj736vNpupbCq0nW4sFz88AhdVcajKuFUTSbEFQWLaJEsaYG1WnllpvKsyBnbERGm@3rjoWCWH5VfdIQ@btRWegKV9@g1ImeTlnnoMMsdodrhHQ2zaJC2uMU5RdEmiZ@bGQ@mzy1m7WwZTImRdm80RM6R5GLjOakDKA2XC4PYj7vLBU@smUXjJuFBPG4xa5NlEDvdp3GZNZNDnrVo@NOUHLE8Fzt6ZR4xfov2u56DIKS9zfER4jhd98tqTLsTvXntGefY4Worw@9GWXmvtPRWTgX6l73iXA@Ci9vRn3EbfqvmSPxsDG894r8ChxRGACkuGAQHuKx0EPwNM1fojhD6P3UD/lo3@nzwzw0Cwwt6APjSMGdmELh3/XEG6BwDBwj6IfogA/SOboz@oW5056w7/QQ)

Basically I expand the positions of the P's whenever a white space is around until it reaches (or not) the border of the layout.

Some licenses:

- I use a `char[][]` as the input for the layout.
- Returns `0` as insecure and `1` as secure.

Comment: You can't take extra input to the function so you can assume the dimensions... Unless you can find a meta post to persuade me otherwise.

Comment: `1>0` and `1<0` are shorter than `true` and `false`.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder more and more amazed with your tips! I was afraid that the extra parameters were too much, so I changed the answer.

Comment: Can `==0` become `<1`? You have at least 1 byte of irrelevant whitespace. Can you remove the `new[]`s? (Doesn't always work but sometimes does like in `int[] n = {1,2,3};`).

Comment: Inputting a multidimensional array instead if a jagged one may save you some bytes i.e. `char[,]` and seeing as you are padding the input to a rectangle anyway it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder if I change `char[][]` with `char[,]` then `m.Length` becomes `m.GetLength(0)` and `m[0].Length` becomes `m.GetLength(1)` which are larger, but maybe the rest of the code gets shorter enough. As for the irrelevant whitespace, I always slip some of them, no matter how much I try... :)

Comment: @TheLethalCoder funny, the code remains the same length after the change, so I'll leave it as is. :)

Comment: Me too, I've been meaning to create a small tool for removing the whitespace in C# but I've never gotten around to it. And haha unfortunate.

Comment: `{m[x][y]= p; c.Push(new[]` -> `{m[x][y]=p;c.Push(new[]`

Comment: You can compare `char`s to `int`s so I believe you can replace the `==' '` to `==32` to save bytes. You should be able to do this on similar comparisons as well.

Comment: 408: `m=>{var p='P';int a=m.Length,b=m[0].Length,i=0,j,x,y;var c=new System.Collections.Stack();for(;i<a;i++)for(j=0;j<b;j++)if(m[i][j]==p)c.Push(new[]{i,j});while(c.Count>0){var t=(int[])c.Pop();x=t[0];y=t[1];if(x<1|x>a-2|y<1|y>b-2)return 0;foreach(var v in new[]{-1,1}){var z=x>0&x<a-1&y>0&y<b-1;if(z&m[x+v][y]==32){m[x][y]=p;c.Push(new[]{x+v,y});}if(z&m[x][y+v]==32){m[x][y]=p;c.Push(new[]{x,y+v});}}}return 1;}`

Comment: Sorry for all the small improvements but I'm not the best at spotting lots at once...

Comment: @TheLethalCoder at first I used the `new int[]{-1,1}` in two `foreach` loops, but I reduced them to one and then I forgot to move the array into the declaration of the loop. And once again I forgot to move all the declarations of `int`s into the same place.

Comment: Moving `x` and `y` into the main declaration didn't save us any bytes but it's could practice for golfing :)

Answer (score 15):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 69 bytes

*-10 bytes thanks to [@Grimy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6484/grimy).*

*-2 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).*

77 byte of code + `-p0` flags.

```perl
/
/;$_=s/(P| )(.{@{-}})?(?!\1)(?1)/P$2P/s?redo:!/\A.*P|P.*\Z|^P|P$/m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU7BCoJAEL3vV4zoQQPdCroYYUF1rDl0CmmxWlAwk3U9SPbttm4lBtWDffNmeG92ci7SSWMauarg5sOGEjq12KygNtbg2N5tfnPvdyewAyMcOXYwcihaY6RFIPj56hs0XHgDrNEbhPv6oIRFLw1jq82SMbKVMReQZHkpC5BxJOEUZXDkIEXCzz4hO1HKuPKJ2QcxAUFBU9sp1g/b7sNJ1lFa8OpLXiXQ/JuHNv88QE9Bo7MrCZ0mr3i7HeDt7r7H/iF6R4/VBJsf8wc)

Some *short* explanations:
The idea is to put a `P` everywhere the prisoners can go. If any `P` is on the first/last line, or the first/last column, then the prisoners can go there and therefor escape, which means the prison isn't secure.
`s/(P| )(.{@{-}})?(?!\1)(?1)/P$2P/s` replaces a space on the right of or bellow a `P` with a `P`, or a space on the left or on top of a `P`.
Finally, `/\A.*P|P.*\Z|^P|P$/m` checks if a line starts or ends with a `P`, or if there is a `P` on the first or the last line.

Comment: cool approach using regexps! (but probably VERY expensive when the space grows)

Comment: Actually, it's not *that* inefficient. In particular, it doesn't require a lot of backtracking, there are not `*` or `+`, the longest match it can do is the size of a line... Now of course if you compare with an approach more manual, based on arrays for instance, then yes it's quite inefficient!

Comment: Can you use `\A` and `\Z` to avoid having to have a separate regex with the `/m` modifier?

Comment: @Neil Right, thanks! I tend to forget about those assertions because `^` and `$` are usually shorter, but here it's useful! :)

Comment: -1 byte by using `/\n/` instead of `/.*/`, and `@{-}` instead of `@{+}` (where `\n` means a literal newline).

Comment: -6 bytes by merging the two substitutions: `s/P(.{@{-}})? | (.{@{-}})?P/P$1$2P/s`.

Comment: -2 bytes by golfing the merged substitution: `s/(P| )(.{@{-}})?(?!\1)(?1)/P$2P/s`.

Comment: @Grimy very nice golfing of the regex! Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>134</s> 133 bytes

Takes input as an array of arrays of characters. Returns `0` (insecure) or `1` (secure).

```js
f=a=>a.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>c>'O'&&[-1,1,0,0].map((X,i)=>(R=a[y+1-'1102'[i]])&&R[X+=x]?R[X]<'!'?R[o=2,X]=c:0:o=0)),o=1)|o&2?f(a):o
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=a=>a.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>c>'O'&&[-1,1,0,0].map((X,i)=>(R=a[y+1-'1102'[i]])&&R[X+=x]?R[X]<'!'?R[o=2,X]=c:0:o=0)),o=1)|o&2?f(a):o

console.log(f([
  [...'#############'],
  [...'# P #  P#   #'],
  [...'#   #   # P #'],
  [...'#############']
]))

console.log(f([
  [...'#############'],
  [...'# P    P    #'],
  [...'#   #   # P #'],
  [...'#############']
]))

console.log(f([
  [...'#############'],
  [...'# P #  P#   #'],
  [...'#   #   # P #'],
  [...'########## ##']
]))

console.log(f([
  [...'####'],
  [...'#   #'],
  [...' #   #'],
  [...'  # P ####'],
  [...'  ####']
]))

console.log(f([
  [...'P']
]))

console.log(f([
  [...'###'],
  [...'# #'],
  [...'# #'],
  [...'### P']
]))
```

Comment: Can the `&&`s just be `&`?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Not the first one, but the second one can be replaced by `|`. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't know the spread operator worked on strings. Cool!

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 121 bytes

```
f=s=>s==(s=s.replace(eval('/( |P)([^]{'+s.search`
`+'})?(?!\\1)[ P]/'),'P$2P'))?!/^.*P|P.*$/.test(s)&!/^P|P$/m.test(s):f(s)
```

Takes input as a newline-delimited rectangular string. Returns 0 for insecure and 1 for secure. Based on my answer to [Detect Failing Castles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109015), although it would be more efficient to test for an escaped prisoner at each step, rather than once they'd finished exploring the prison.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 40 bytes

```apl
{⊃2≠(××{1⊃⌈/⍵,⍉⍵}⌺3 3)⍣≡(⌽1,⍉)⍣4⊢'# '⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nU3LasJQEN3frxjI4ipUNNWVX3F/4aKkhAZSGjcibmxRk@aKLiS7onbrrrgRXOVPzo@kcxOpdiEFB@ZxzpyZo1@CRn@og/Cp0Qt0FPm9Aou1H2K6bBUe1xGSt0fEm1qe5dnIZYR03oQ5PMDE3MZIj21q12G@EG9rSE@u3VjcQbKTDkmYbyssikH5zxwQ71559HivLZVnzEQ8wXx2MZ@V35NJhI93TFelidl3paf9QGomZfgsx0IMyBXOdQiHFDlEipMsIqpSWfRHeeOYoyz/HrfucqZr50ol6NwqseWJLi7q14zl5@Q/SvwA)

`'# '⍳⍵` encode `'#'`, `' '`, `'P'` as 0 1 2

`(⌽1,⍉)⍣4` surround with 1s

`(××{1⊃⌈/⍵,⍉⍵}⌺3 3)⍣≡` max-of-neighbours flood fill of non-zero cells

`⊃2≠` do we not have a 2 at the top left?

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>64</s> 55 bytes

```matlab
@(a,z=padarray(a,[1 1]))~nnz(bwfill(z==35,1,1,4)&z>35);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNRp8q2IDElsagosRLIiTZUMIzV1KzLy6vSSCpPy8zJ0aiytTU21TEEQhNNtSo7Y1NN6/@JecUa0Xp6elzqyshAHchXCFBQVlAIAGIFCF9BAYIDIHw4UACqj9Xk@g8A)

or

[Verify all test cases!](https://tio.run/##pY5BCsIwFET3OcVAwCTQTaldScQjZF@6@NYWhFClVMWIXj1GU2qLG8EJP2Qg8@Yfqp7Otfee9I0Vgk8lwASHAQdMGHDx8kAcE/0sULIvRkQEva8/EL9tgSlCYNSQCX8xPmI8NgCfdiNKTDXgBOa4uMhQjxBi9xVjVW1tc2rlRlLi9JF21HV0DaZIkZZKPdrWye2l2VsrndZZnqThLNXCrbNcJaT8Ew)

Explanation:

```matlab
z=padarray(a,[1 1])       %add a boundary(of 0s) around the scene
F = bwfill(z==35,1,1,4)   %flood fill the prison starting from the boundary
~nnz(F&z>35);             %if position of at least a prisoner  is filled then the prison is not secure
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 35 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)<sup>CP437</sup>

```
ä¬my■╡╤▲l@┤êr*⌠\¶ƒläå─▄¶√¿ [Uy⌠Só4↔
```

[Try it online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%C3%A4%C2%ACmy%E2%96%A0%E2%95%A1%E2%95%A4%E2%96%B2l%40%E2%94%A4%C3%AAr*%E2%8C%A0%5C%C2%B6%C6%92l%C3%A4%C3%A5%E2%94%80%E2%96%84%C2%B6%E2%88%9A%C2%BF+%5BUy%E2%8C%A0S%C3%B34%E2%86%94&i=%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%0A%23+P+%23++P%23+++%23%0A%23+++%23+++%23+P+%23%0A%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%0A%0A%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%0A%23+P++++P++++%23%0A%23+++%23+++%23+P+%23%0A%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%0A%0A%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%0A%23+P+%23++P%23+++%23%0A%23+++%23+++%23+P+%23%0A%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23+%23%23%0A%0A%23%23%23%23++++++++++%0A%23+++%23%0A+%23+++%23%0A++%23+P+%23%23%23%23%0A++%23%23%23%23%0A%0AP+++++++++++++%0A%0A%23%23%23+++++++++++%0A%23+%23%0A%23+%23%0A%23%23%23+P&a=1&m=1)

Surely golfing language without an internal to handle path-finding can do this as well!

### Explanation

Uses the unpacked format to explain.

```
zLz]Y+Mys+y+{{{" P|P ""PP"Rm}Y!My!Mgphh' =
zLz]Y+Mys+y+                                  Surround the original matrix with four borders of whitespaces
            {                      gp         Iterate until a fixed point is found, return the single fixed point
             {              }Y!               Store the block in register Y and execute it
              {" P|P ""PP"Rm                  For each row, flood every space adjacent to a P with P.
                               My!            Transpose the matrix and do the flooding again
                                     hh' =    The final matrix has a space on the upper left corner that has not been flooded by P
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>154</s> 146 bytes

I was hoping an answer using flood fill would be shorter than this.

```
DEF S P
FOR J=0TO 1X=1Y=1FOR I=0TO LEN(P)-1GPSET X,Y,-(P[I]=="#")GPAINT X,Y,-1,-J*(P[I]>@A)X=X*(P[I]>"31")+1INC Y,X<2NEXT
NEXT?!GSPOIT(0,0)GCLS
END
```

Replace `31` with the corresponding ASCII character.